# What does 「風が強く吹いている。」 mean?

Tags: grammar, verbs, transitivity

According to the dictionary, 吹く is a transitive verb (e.g., a verb that needs an object).

However, the following sentence does not have an object. So what should I  translate it?

> 風が強く吹いている。

Comment: 明鏡国語辞典 lists 吹く as transitive and intransitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://www.nihongokyoshi.co.jp/manbow/manbow.php?id=960&TAB=2), 吹く can be transitive and intransitive.

> 風が吹く（自動詞）　笛を吹く（他動詞）

So 風が強く吹いている。 can translate to "(lit.) The wind is blowing hard." i.e. "It's blowing hard."

Comment: So when it is windy, "風が吹" is the appropriate phrase, akin to how when its raining, you say "雨が降る"?

Comment: @user11589 You'd say 雨が降って(い)る or just 雨だ / 雨です when it's rainy, and when it's windy you'd say 風が強い(lit. The wind is strong.), 風がある(lit. There's wind.), 風が吹いて(い)る(The wind is blowing.), 強い風が吹いてる(Strong wind is blowing.), けっこう/かなり風が吹いてる/風がある, etc...

Answer (score 4):

As choco writes, “吹く” can be used in both ways of transitive and intransitive as a verb, though I think it’s more often used in a transitive than in intransitive form. Here are some examples I picked up at random:

(Transitive):

笛を吹く- play the flute

埃を吹く- blow the dust off

[法螺]{ほら}を吹く- talk big

毛を吹いて傷を求める - suffer great damage by sticking to a trivial matter

息を吹き返す - come back to life

ひと泡吹かせる - flummox someone / give sb a scare

(Intransitive):

そよ風が吹く - A light wind breezes

芽が吹く - The buds sprout.

泉水の水が吹く - The fountain water springs out.

嵐が吹き荒れる - The storm blows violently.

どこ吹く風 - I don't (he, she doesn't) care at all.